# Error when setting up MySql Server in Windows 10

Tags: mysql

Friends,

I am getting this below error on the logs when trying to setup MySql Server 8.0.23 - x64. I have the prerequisites Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable 2015-2019 installed.

Requesting for your help in resolving this issue.

```
1: Action 15:07:34: INSTALL. 
1: 1: MySQL Server 8.0 2: {41861802-A301-491E-882B-F28957D17F82} 
1: Action 15:07:34: FindRelatedProducts. Searching for related applications
1: Action 15:07:34: AppSearch. Searching for installed applications
1: Action 15:07:34: DwordToNumber. 
1: 1: MySQL Server 8.0 2: {41861802-A301-491E-882B-F28957D17F82} 3: 3 
1: The action 'Install' for product 'MySQL Server 8.0.23' failed.
```

Comment: The most common reason of this issue is broken Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable installation - it can be both latest and some previous version installed in the system. Open Programs and Components (in control panel - installed programs), then select each Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable installed and perform Repair action. Maybe some of them will report about lost file or folder - find the installator for strictly the same build and execute repairing via it.

Comment: 1) This question has nothing to do with programming, therefore it is off topic here on SO. DBA sister site of SO is there to help with database operations related questions like this one. 2) The DBAs will not be able to help you based on this information alone as it basically says that something went wrong, but does not say what.

Comment: Dear @Akina - I tried doing a repair action on the Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable which was already installed. I am still facing the same problem.